# Update watchOS-only app "generated iOS" plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, watchos

**TL;DR how do you update the generated watchOS-only iOS plist file?**

---

watchOS-only apps have by default 3 targets: WatchKit App, WatchKit Extension and what look to be the main bundle, something resembling a *"fake" iOS app*, likely needed for distribution.

[image: watchOS-only app targets]

In the build steps you can clearly see that the main "TeslaPulse" target is an iOS target and is the parent bundle of the WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension (kinda like it is for non watchOS-only apps).

This main iOS target has one step doing this:

```
ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.app/Info.plist /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TeslaPulse.build/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.build/empty.plist (in target 'TeslaPulse' from project 'TeslaPulse')
    cd /Users/vince/Documents/TeslaPulse
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TeslaPulse.build/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.build/empty.plist -producttype com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2-container -genpkginfo /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphoneos -additionalcontentfile /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TeslaPulse.build/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.build/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen-SBPartialInfo.plist -additionalcontentfile /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TeslaPulse.build/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist -additionalcontentfile /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TeslaPulse.build/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.build/ProductTypeInfoPlistAdditions.plist -requiredArchitecture arm64 -o /Users/vince/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeslaPulse-dotmlbmrjsjjgggixtbkfceylkfa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TeslaPulse.app/Info.plist
```

That's **generating** the Info.plist for that main target.

**Question: How does one change that plist to have an extra key?**

This is needed because of https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/405719#405719 where in order for your app to be available to internal users for TestFlight you somehow need to explicitly add the `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` key.

Though for watchOS-only apps like mine, the only trick I found to workaround the issue was to manually change the generated plist **after** the archive was generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the same problem, you should be able to add the key into the main WatchApp. But iTunesConnect is checking watch apps as if they're bundled inside an iPhone app:
`ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90363: "Invalid Info.plist key. The key 'ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption' in bundle Boiler.app/Watch/WatchKit App.app is invalid."`

I found a nice solution, by just creating an info.plist for the dummy target! That will be merged instead of the empty.plist! Don't forget to `INFOPLIST_FILE` of the Build settings of the dummy target. (source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122660)

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks. It looks like iTunes connect has been patched since and it’s not complaining about that missing key anymore. Nonetheless your workaround is great (;

Comment: It works with Xcode 14.3, thx!